# Coloring footnotes (mark and text)

Tags: footnotes

(A) In order to make the footnote symbols red, I include the following command in the beginning of my LaTeX documents:

```
\renewcommand\thefootnote{\textcolor{red}{\fnsymbol{footnote}}}
```

But what similar thing can I write to make [also] the text in the footnotes red? Have tried myself and googled in vain – Please keep it simple (an explicit command line like the one above) thanks!

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article} 
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, amsthm, cite, graphicx, color, setspace} 
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor} 
\usepackage[multiple]{footmisc} 
\linespread{1.3} 

\renewcommand\thefootnote{\textcolor{red}{\fnsymbol{footnote}}} 

\usepackage[hmargin=3.2cm,vmargin=4.2cm]{geometry} 
\usepackage{soul} 
\setul{}{4pt} 

\begin{document} 
\title{} 
\date{} 
\setul{}{1pt} 
An example of a number\footnote{Numbers are fun.} is $5.$ 
\end{document}
```

(B) If I have a folder with hundreds of LeTeX files and I want to include this in all of them (so all of these footnote texts become red), is there any *simple* way of doing this? I am not good at computers, so please rather write 'no' than something complicated.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436)! Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Please insert the code in the original question.

Comment: Did that thx. 

Would appreciate (A) help. 

(B) I can fix in a tiresome but elementary way.

Comment: For B): Assuming that all your LaTeX files use the same document class, namely article, you could — as a somewhat hacky work-around — copy the file `article.cls` from `/tex/latex/base/article.cls` into your working directory and append the lines between `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` from my answer.

Answer (score 2):

For A): You may want to redefine the command `\@makefntext` as well, which is, however, defined differently depending on the document class you use:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article} 
\usepackage{xcolor} 

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\thefootnote{\textcolor{red}{\fnsymbol{footnote}}}
\renewcommand\@makefntext[1]{%
  \parindent 1em%
  \noindent
  \hb@xt@1.8em{\hss\@makefnmark}\textcolor{red}{#1}}
\makeatother

\begin{document} 
An example of a number\footnote{Numbers are fun.} is $5$. 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Cheers Jasper Habicht for you answers! My footnote-text becomes red. :)

Since I'm LaTeX-dummy who can't quite break down each of the ingredients in your trick: I wanted to make footnote-texts all red, not change anything else. Is that what your commando does? (I didn't understand whether "You may want to redefine..." meant you changed something else or that I could do this if I wanted to by adding something additional.) Thx again.

Comment: My code takes your code (that redefines `\thefootnote` being the macro to insert the footnote symbol) and just adds another redefinition of the macro to insert the footnote text. Because the redefinition of this second macro contains the letter `@`, which cannot be used just so, the two commands `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` have to be put before and after this macro redefinition. In short, if you replace your single line of code with my few lines, both, the footnote symbol and the footnote text will become red, just as you wanted. The code is supposed to do exactly that, nothing else.